# how to get space in edittext filter using custom listview? does it possible? using simple adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-edittext

I have custom listview using simple adapter, Currently I have issue regarding filter that I have custom list data with numbers and characters in listview.

If I enter name then its give one blank space the filter results gets disappear.

I have list data like name then number for example : NAME 123, Whenever I enter name then gives space in that edit text then results are gone and list-view gets disappears.

I have tried this on below link but they used Array adapter, So my question is is it possible only in Array adapter or I can used simple adapter?

Android listview edittext filter space button?
If yes then how can I implement, kindly help. Advance thank you.

Here I enter name then enter space after results show enter numbers, after enter number results getting disappear.

public class GlobalSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView listOne;
SimpleAdapter ADA;
ActionBar actionBar;

EditText etSearch; 
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_global_search);

    listOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    etSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE
            );
        }
    });
    try {
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {



            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                GlobalSearch.this.ADA.getFilter().filter(etSearch.getText().toString().trim());


            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String z) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), z, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            String[] from = {"A","A1","B","C", "D"};
            int[] views = {R.id.lbl1,R.id.lbl2,R.id.lbl3,R.id.lbl4, R.id.lblShift};

            ADA = new SimpleAdapter(GlobalSearch.this, proList,
                    R.layout.list_layout_global_search, from, views);

            listOne.setAdapter(ADA);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
searchView.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                          KeyEvent event) {
return true;
}
});
addTextChangeListener();
```

**now create method addTextChangeListener**

```
        private void addTextChangeListener() {
     searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

    query = query.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<CityDataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();



    final CharSequence finalQuery = query;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Clear the filter list
            filteredList.clear();

            // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finalQuery)) {

                filteredList.addAll(cities);

            } else {
                // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                for (CityDataModel item : cities) {
                    if (item.getCity_name().toLowerCase().contains(finalQuery.toString().toLowerCase())
                            ) {
                        // Adding Matched items
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set on UI Thread
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                    adapter = new SearchCityAdapter(SearchCityClass.this, filteredList);
                    recyclerSearchCity.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();


}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
 });
  }
```

Comment: can you send me demo of this listview using filter? by getting one layout, and that layout having custom listview. Nilesh Rathod

Comment: just replace your  array list with my arraylist it will work ask me if u feel any diffyculy